# Remove add-in in saved document

Tags: ms-word, office-js

If I save a Word document with my add-in open and opens the document on another computer that does not have my add-in installed, Word asks if the user trusts the add-in. If the user chooses to trust the add-in it is installed on the user computer. Is there any way to avoid this behavior.

My add-in is used to insert comments in to the document but the add-in is not meant for the recipients of the document.

<s>It only seems to be the case on Mac.</s>

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen, when you close a taskpane, it is not really removed from the document -- it is just "hidden". If you want to "export out" a document and have the taskpane removed completely, go to **Info -> Check for Issues**, make sure that the "Task Pane Add-ins" is checked, click "Inspect", and then confirm that you want the taskpanes removed.

[image]

More info on Document Inspector here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-by-inspecting-documents-356b7b5d-77af-44fe-a07f-9aa4d085966f

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael. How can this be done on Mac?

Comment: From a quick search, it doesn't appear that Document Inspector is available on the Mac, unfortunately (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac/using-document-inspector-to-find-personally/a6d726e6-89b1-499a-aed7-895c595d2267).  You could probably achieve a similar effect through opening up the document as if it's a zip file, removing the taskpane part(s), and re-zipping it back (http://superuser.com/questions/411911/re-zipped-docx-files-dont-open-in-word), but it's not super-convenient either.  Please feel free to open a suggestion on https://word.uservoice.com/